# Redundant loop inside a process (VHDL)?

Tags: loops, process, vhdl

I'm taking a university course to learn digital design using VHDL, and was doing some reading in the book the other day where I came across the following piece of code:

```
architecture abstract of computer_system is
    ...

    cpu : process is
        variable instr_reg : word;
        variable PC : natural;
        ...
    begin
        loop
            address <= PC;
            mem_read <= '1';
            wait until mem_ready;
            ...
        end loop;
    end process cpu;
end architecture abstract;
```

Now, as I've understood it, once a process reaches its last statement, it will go back and execute the first statement (provided that the last statement wasn't a `wait`, of course). And the purpose of `loop ... end loop;` is to repeat the intermediate code indefinitely. So doesn't that make the loop redundant in this case? Does it add any extra behaviour that isn't already exhibited by the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're spot on as far as I can see, no need to have a loop in there.

Comment: As there has been no more entries, I'm assuming this to be an acceptable answer.